# Browsers & other programs won't work

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, browser

So my friend says he dropped his laptop the other day, and since then his browsers (IE, Chrome) won't even open anymore. They always show the same message:
"Whoa! Google Chrome has crashed. Restart Now?"
IE won't work anymore
Also Teamviewer doens't work anymore, and I tried installing Opera browser, but it didn't respond as well, when I opened the .exe file.

EDIT. Windows Update can download and update, also Popcorn time can download and view the movie. (So the internet works)

The following solutions I've already tried, but without result:
Reinstalling Chrome
Installing Opera browser
Did a full virus scan & full antimalware scan
WinSock and TCP/IP Refresh
File System Check (SFC.exe /SCANNOW)
Anyone has any ideas what are the optional solutions left?

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't this be in SE superuser?

Answer (score 0):

There could be a lot of reasons. My first guess is that the *wininet.dll* doesn't work properly. It's located at 
"*C:\Windows\System32\wininet.dll*". Maybe you can check that the file isn't corrupted and/or try to replace it with a valid one (e.g. [here's a debug version](https://support.microsoft.com/en-en/kb/884931)).